# Thevenin theorem and its example

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, electronics

[image: thevenin theorem.]

Calculate the current through 4 ohm resistance using this theorem. I am not getting any idea on how to solve this problem when there are two  AC 
voltages.

Comment: I fear that some theorists here will close and move this question to electrical engineering because they don't know that understanding and using electrical circuits is a necessity for experimental physicists.

Answer (score 3):

Sources being AC doesn't change anything. It's just that their value depends on time, and so will Thevenin's equivalent voltage $V_{th}$. BEsides that, the procedure is exactly the same.

1. See clearly what are the terminals. You want the current through the $4\Omega$ resistance, for which you want to simplify the rest. You want the equivalent of the rest of the circuit.  That means, erase the $4\Omega$ resitance, and that's what you wanna convert into a Thevenin circuit.
2. Start with the equivalent resistance. For that, you just CANCEL all independent sources. Caution: not the dependent ones.

In your circuit there are no dependent sources, you have nothing like a source of `4 times the voltage of another element`; all sources have a value that doesn't depend on other elements, so they are independent.

How would you cancel the effect of sources? Turning their values to 0. But... a 0V source is the same as changing it for just a continuation of the wire.

Caution: in LAB you must never short-circuit a source. You don't add a wire, but **replace** the source using a wire.

So, you see now the sources have both dissapeared. There are only two resistances remaining, and from terminals A and B, they are in parallel, so the equivalent resistance is teh parallel of 5 and 10 $\Omega$.

3. Finally, for the equivalent voltage, you bring back the voltage sources and find the voltages in both terminals. The substraction is what you're looking for.

Comment: I fear that some theorists here will close and move this question to electrical engineering because they don't know that understanding and using electrical circuits is a necessity for experimental physicists.

Answer (score 0):

The Thevenin Theorem considers the behavior of a circuit at a chosen terminal. It posits that you can replace the behavior of a circuit (with possibly many voltage/current sources) at this terminal by a single voltage source, the Thevenin voltage, $V_{th}$ in series with a single impedance (resistor).

(1) The Thevenin voltage is obtained by determining the open voltage at the terminal (when you remove the 4 Ohm resistor) with voltage/current sources in place.

(2) The series resistor you'll get by replacing in the circuit all voltage sources by shorts and current sources by opens and then you determine the impedance/resistance at the chosen terminal.

Comment: Please tell me the answers, I want to check mine.

Comment: @user524694 - I get $V_{th}= 1V$ and $R_{th}=10/3 \Omega$ Thus the current through the resistor should be $I=\frac {1V}{10/3+4 \Omega}=3/22 A$.Hope there is no mistake